# Rails validation of non-models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I was just wondering what the recommended approach would be for validating a form that is **not** based on a model. I agree that generally all validation should be done in models but there are situations where a particular form might not have a corresponding model(s). For example, an arbitrary search form.

Based on my current research, there are two main ways of doing it as far as I can see,

1. Validate in the controller.

   - Is it possible to utilise the Rails validations in the controller? I really would prefer to use them over my own custom code.
2. Create an arbitrary class eg. called `SearchForm` and include the `ActiveRecord::Validations`

   - Should the class be stored with the models (even though it isn't really)?
   - The posts that recommended this approach indicated you have to stub out a bunch of methods for ActiveRecord such as save, save!, update_attribute, etc. This strikes me as not very Rubyesque at all!
3. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Absolutely **#2**. **[ActiveModel::Validations API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html)** is what you're looking for

```
class ArbitrarySearch
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :query

  validate :query, :presence
end
```

As for where this should go, yes, it should go in `app/models`. If you're like me and think the mix of models extending `ActiveRecord::Base` and those that don't coexisting within the same directory smells funny, consider adding the following to your `config/application.rb` file

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

Now, you can organize your model files in whatever way you like. For me I have

```
- app
  |
  |- models
     |
     |- table
     |- tableless
     |- observer
```

and I drop classes like your `ArbitrarySearch` class into `app/models/tableless/arbitrary_search.rb`.

---

There is a great gem to get this and other common functionality you use within ActiveRecord models into generic non-table-based model classes called **[active_attr](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr)**.

> ActiveAttr is a set of modules that makes it easy to create plain old ruby models with functionality found in ORMs, like ActiveRecord, without reinventing the wheel. Think of ActiveAttr as the stuff ActiveModel left out.

Comment: Thanks for the really clear and concise answer plus all the other tips too!